# Session values not being saved

Tags: php, session

I tried the simple code below after my login page was not working correctly:
(Same code works on local server just fine)

```
<?php session_start();   ?>
 <html>
    <head>
            <title>Test</title>
            <?php



        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
        {
            $_SESSION['login']="1";
        }
        if($_SESSION['login']=="1")
        {
            print "You're Logged In!";
        }
        else
        {
            print "Not logged in";

        }



        ?>
</head>
<body>
        <form name=form1 method=post action=testing.php>
            <input type=submit name=submit1>
        </form>

        </body>
</html>
```

When pressing the button it works fine but when I open the page again (using the link to the page), session data is not saved. How can I fix this?
Here is my session info:
[image]

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: @Barmar I tried it local server and it worked there, too. That's why I guess it should be something about the server.

Comment: Do you see the PHPSESSID cookie when you check cookies in Developer Tools?

Comment: Go into the Resources tab and click on Cookies to see the cookies that are saved with the page.

Comment: I checked, there is no cookies save for this page. However there is PHPSESSID cookie when I try the code on local server. Is that the problem?

Comment: It sounds like you may be blocking cookies from the server. Check your browser settings.

Comment: I checked it on firefox, it works there! How come Microsoft edge doesn't block cookies on local server but does for online version?

Comment: Check the security and privacy settings in the browser.

Comment: It is set not to block cookies.

Comment: Well, it obviously is. I don't know Edge, but if it's like IE it has different network zones with different security properties. So the local server is in a low-protection zone, the remote server is in a high-protection zone.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, I'll just keep using Firefox then.